# Example Code for MemCached in C

Tags: c, memcached

I am looking for some sample C code for using memcache to set a value

1. Connecting to Server/Port
2. using multiple memcache_set
3. Close

I have the app running in PHP in 5 lines of code but can not find any good memcache samples in C which I need to port to.

Comment: This sounds like homework... If you're serious about wanting an answer, you should post the PHP app.

Comment: talk about a trivial question :/. If you can program C you should be competent enough to read C. Memcached is a super simple program.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://github.com/smerrill/libmemcached-example/blob/master/memcached.c) is a great memcached sample in C

```
#include <libmemcached/memcached.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  //memcached_servers_parse (char *server_strings);
  memcached_server_st *servers = NULL;
  memcached_st *memc;
  memcached_return rc;
  char *key = "keystring";
  char *value = "keyvalue";

  char *retrieved_value;
  size_t value_length;
  uint32_t flags;

  memc = memcached_create(NULL);
  servers = memcached_server_list_append(servers, "localhost", 11211, &rc);
  rc = memcached_server_push(memc, servers);

  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr, "Added server successfully\n");
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't add server: %s\n", memcached_strerror(memc, rc));

  rc = memcached_set(memc, key, strlen(key), value, strlen(value), (time_t)0, (uint32_t)0);

  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr, "Key stored successfully\n");
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't store key: %s\n", memcached_strerror(memc, rc));

  retrieved_value = memcached_get(memc, key, strlen(key), &value_length, &flags, &rc);
  printf("Yay!\n");

  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Key retrieved successfully\n");
    printf("The key '%s' returned value '%s'.\n", key, retrieved_value);
    free(retrieved_value);
  }
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't retrieve key: %s\n", memcached_strerror(memc, rc));

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more complete answer, which also shows how to get and delete from a memcached server.  The code is technically in C++, but doesn't use any features that would be unfamiliar to most C programmers.

To compile: `g++ sample.cc -o sample -ggdb -O3 -lmemcached`

To run: `./sample -s localhost -p 11211`

The functions whose names begin with `mcd_` show the basics of inserting, deleting, and getting, as well as connecting and disconnecting from memcached.  The remaining code makes use of those functions to insert 50 key/value pairs, verify they all are in the server, remove half the pairs, and then verify that the right keys remain / are gone.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

#include <libmemcached/memcached.h>

// NB: I know that `using namespace std` at global scope is bad form, and that
//     global variables are bad form.  However, they help keep this answer under
//     200 lines.
using namespace std;

/// The connection to memcached
memcached_st *mcd;

/// A global set of key/value pairs that we manufacture for the sake of this
/// example
vector<pair<string, string>> kv_pairs;

/// Put a key/value pair into memcached with expiration 0, no special flags
bool mcd_set(const string &key, const string &val) {
  auto rc = memcached_set(mcd, key.c_str(), key.length(), val.c_str(),
                          val.length(), (time_t)0, (uint32_t)0);
  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    return true;
  cout << "Error in mcd_set(): " << memcached_strerror(mcd, rc) << endl;
  return false;
}

/// Delete a key/value pair from memcached.  return true on success
/// NB: `(time_t)0` is an expiration of `0`, i.e., immediately
bool mcd_delete(const string &key) {
  auto rc = memcached_delete(mcd, key.c_str(), key.length(), (time_t)0);
  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    return true;
  cout << "Error in mcd_delete(): " << memcached_strerror(mcd, rc) << endl;
  return false;
}

/// Get a value from the kv store, using its key to do the lookup.  return
/// true on success.  On success, the by-ref out parameter `val` will be set.
bool mcd_get(const string &key, string &val) {
  memcached_return rc;
  size_t len;
  uint32_t flags = 0;
  char *res = memcached_get(mcd, key.c_str(), key.length(), &len, &flags, &rc);
  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS) {
    val = string(res, len);
    free(res);
    return true;
  }
  // NB: skip next line, because we don't want error messages on a failed get:
  //
  // cout << "Error in mcd_get(): " << memcached_strerror(mcd, rc) << endl;
  return false;
}

/// Connect to a single memcached server on the provided port
bool mcd_connect(const string &servername, const int port) {
  mcd = memcached_create(nullptr);
  memcached_return rc;
  memcached_server_st *servers = nullptr;
  servers =
      memcached_server_list_append(servers, servername.c_str(), port, &rc);
  rc = memcached_server_push(mcd, servers);
  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS) {
    cout << "  Successfully connected to " << servername << ":" << port << endl;
    return true;
  }
  cout << "Error in mcd_connect(): " << memcached_strerror(mcd, rc) << endl;
  return false;
}

/// Close the connection to memcached
void mcd_shutdown() {
  memcached_free(mcd);
  cout << "  Successfully disconnected\n";
}

/// Create a bunch of key/value pairs
void build_kv_pairs(int howmany) {
  for (int i = 0; i < howmany; ++i) {
    string key = "key" + to_string(i) + "_______";
    string val = "val" + to_string(i);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      val += ("_" + to_string(i));
    kv_pairs.push_back({key, val});
  }
}

/// insert a bunch of k/v pairs into memcached
bool put_kv_pairs(int howmany) {
  for (int i = 0; i < howmany; ++i) {
    if (!mcd_set(kv_pairs[i].first, kv_pairs[i].second)) {
      cout << "Error inserting key `" << kv_pairs[i].first << "`\n";
      return false;
    }
  }
  cout << "  put_kv_pairs(" << howmany << ") completed successfully\n";
  return true;
}

/// Remove a sequence of keys from memcached
///
/// NB: Here and below, we use first/last/stride so that we can vary wich
///     key/value pairs are operated on
bool delete_kv_pairs(int first, int last, int stride) {
  for (int i = first; i <= last; i += stride) {
    if (!mcd_delete(kv_pairs[i].first)) {
      cout << "Error removing key `" << kv_pairs[i].first << "`\n";
      return false;
    }
  }
  cout << "  delete_kv_pairs(" << first << ", " << last << ", " << stride
       << ") completed successfully\n";
  return true;
}

/// Verify that a sequence of keys is in memcached, with the right expected
/// values
bool check_present_pairs(int first, int last, int stride) {
  for (int i = first; i <= last; i += stride) {
    string value;
    if (!mcd_get(kv_pairs[i].first, value)) {
      cout << "Error getting key `" << kv_pairs[i].first
           << "`: key not found\n";
      return false;
    }
    if (value != kv_pairs[i].second) {
      cout << "Value error while getting key `" << kv_pairs[i].first << "`\n";
      cout << "  Expected: `" << kv_pairs[i].second << "`\n";
      cout << "  Found: `" << value << "`\n";
      return false;
    }
  }
  cout << "  check_present_pairs(" << first << ", " << last << ", " << stride
       << ") completed successfully\n";
  return true;
}

/// Verify that a sequence of keys is *not* in memcached
bool check_missing_pairs(int first, int last, int stride) {
  for (int i = first; i <= last; i += stride) {
    string value;
    if (mcd_get(kv_pairs[i].first, value)) {
      cout << "Error getting key `" << kv_pairs[i].first
           << "`: key unexpectedly found\n";
      return false;
    }
  }
  cout << "  check_missing_pairs(" << first << ", " << last << ", " << stride
       << ") completed successfully\n";
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Parse args to get server name (-s) and port (-p)
  string servername = "";
  int port;
  long opt;
  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:p:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
    case 's':
      servername = string(optarg);
      break;
    case 'p':
      port = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    }
  }

  // Create a bunch of key/value pairs to use for the experiments
  int howmany = 50;
  build_kv_pairs(howmany);

  // Connect to memcached
  mcd_connect(servername, port);
  // insert all the pairs, make sure they are all present
  put_kv_pairs(howmany);
  check_present_pairs(0, howmany - 1, 1);
  // Delete the even pairs
  delete_kv_pairs(0, howmany - 2, 2);
  // ensure the odd pairs are present
  check_present_pairs(1, howmany - 1, 2);
  // ensure the even pairs are not present
  check_missing_pairs(0, howmany, 2);

  mcd_shutdown();
}
```

The code should produce output like the following:

```sh
    Successfully connected to localhost:11211
    put_kv_pairs(50) completed successfully
    check_present_pairs(0, 49, 1) completed successfully
    delete_kv_pairs(0, 48, 2) completed successfully
    check_present_pairs(1, 49, 2) completed successfully
    check_missing_pairs(0, 50, 2) completed successfully
    Successfully disconnected
```